# c#, Erase array inside a list and add date and time to every post

Tags: c#, arrays, list, date, erase

I have just made a logbook that lets the user add a title and a post to a book. And then they have the option to print it out, search for it, erase it or quit the program. The only problems I have is in case 4, how do I let the user erase his post in case 4? And my other problem is that I want the date and time to be added to every post, and I want it to be printed out everytime that post is shown. Would appreciate any answers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Loggbok
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime tiden = DateTime.UtcNow;
            bool running = true;//Ger ett booleskt värde till variabeln     running för att kunna skapa en loop
            List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]>();
            // int loggIndex = 0; // Används för att fylla Arrayen
            while (running)//Här skapas loopen
            {

            Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till loggboken!");
            Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Skriv ett inlägg");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Skriv ut alla inlägg");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Sök inlägg");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Radera innehåll");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta loggbok");
            Console.Write("\nVälj: ");

            int option;

            try
            {
                option = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");
                continue;
            }

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    string[] logg = new string[2];
                    Console.WriteLine(tiden);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange en Titel");
                    logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange text");
                    logg[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                    loggbok.Add(logg);
                    break;


                case 2:
                    foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine(item[1]);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;




                case 3:

                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord du vill söka efter i loggboken");
                    var nyckelord = Console.ReadLine();
                    var entries = loggbok.Where(entry => entry.Any(item =>item.IndexOf(nyckelord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1));
                    foreach (var entry in entries)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", entry));
                    }
                    if (entries.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Din sökning misslyckades...");
                    }
                    break;



                case 4:

                    break;


                case 5:

                    running = false;
                    break;



            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add the timestamp to the title:

```
logg[0] = String.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Console.ReadLine());
```

If you want to add the timestamp to the body instead, just replace `logg[0]` with `logg[1]`.

The above will for example result in:

```
[2017-04-17 23:48:34] This is my post
```

You can also put it after the body:

```
logg[1] = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Console.ReadLine(), Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

...which will result in:

```
This is the body.
2017-04-17 23:48:34
```

---

To remove a post by its title you'd have to iterate the entire list and check each title until you find one that matches the user's input.

This will remove the first post that it can find by the specified title:

```
Console.WriteLine("Skriv titeln på det inlägg du vill ta bort:")
string title = Console.ReadLine();

for(int x = 0; x < loggbok.Count; x++) //Loopa igenom varje inlägg.
{
    if(String.Equals(loggbok[x][0], title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //Icke skiftlägeskänslig matchning av titeln.
    {
        loggbok.RemoveAt(x); //Matchning funnen.
        break; //Avsluta loopen.
    }
}
```

Note that for this particular code to work, you must not include the timestamp in the title.

Comment: This works! But I want the time when you wrote the title to be printed out, is that possible? Because right now it seems to print out the current time

Comment: @mackanmorre : I'm not sure what you mean... This code is supposed to be put into `case 1`, where you create a new post. It will add the time when the title was written. -- Also: _Hej från Sverige! :)_

Comment: @mackanmorre : The code will prepend the title with the date and time that the code was run. Once saved to your `List<string[]>` the timestamp won't change.

Comment: yeah I did that, but it still prints out the current time, not the time when the title was written :P Hej från sverige ;)

Comment: My bad! I read everything completely wrong! Thank you for your help! Tack!

Comment: @mackanmorre : We all make mistakes sometimes ;). Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

For your problem with the date and time you could just do:

```
loggbok.Add(logg + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

That appends the current date and time to your post.

For the problem with erasing a post you could ask the user to enter an index number and then remove the entry with the given index from the list as a start.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but i get this error message: cannot convert from string to string[]